# iOS - How to set the default value of the slider every time the app returns back from Background?

Tags: iphone, ios, slider

I have this slider in my app

```
- (IBAction)slider1:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;  //declare slider
    NSLog(@"%f",slider.value;
}
```

How can I set the default value of the slider every time the app returns back from Background?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this violates the HIG.

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to do is to change the default value of the slider in my app whenever the slider in setting bundles changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an observer for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];


- (void)willEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)n {
    self.slider.value = 0.0f;
}
```